# SQLite Update Method for Android

Tags: android, sqlite, methods

My question is how to you call a method like this.  I already know how to implement it.  Here is the method content:

```
 public boolean updateDebt(long updateId, String debtName, String debtTotal,
        String debtApr, String paymentGoal) {

     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DEBT_NAME, debtName);
     values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DEBT_TOTAL, debtTotal);
     values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_APR, debtApr);
     values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PAYMENT, paymentGoal);
     String whereClause = MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = ?";
     String[] whereArgs = new String[]{ String.valueOf(updateId) };
     return database.update(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_DEBT, values, whereClause, whereArgs) > 0;
```

My questions lies in **calling** this updateDebt Method.

Picture a dialog with four fields with an update button.  The fields are pre-populated with table data.  The user changes field data and hits update, the table should change.

This is the code that comes before the call.  Keep in mind, I am calling it via an onClick inside a dialog inside an onListItemClick.

(I've edit lots of unrelated stuff out)

```
List<Debt> values;
MyArrayAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.debts);

    datasource = new DebtDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();
    values = datasource.getAllDebt();
    adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

  }

 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {

    Debt item = values.get(position);

    final long boxId = item.getId();
    final String BoxName = item.getName();
    final String BoxBalance = item.getBalance();
    final String BoxApr = item.getApr();
    final String BoxPayment = item.getPayment();

 // (edited out: setting up EditText fields here with data from above)

    // set up button
    Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


            datasource.updateDebt(Long.valueOf(boxId), BoxName, BoxBalance,
                    BoxApr, BoxPayment);
            values = datasource.getAllDebt();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

Simply put nothing happens when I hit update.  The dialog dismisses, that' it. Nothing in logcat.  I have logged out the variables just before the update method inside the updateDebt() method.  I have toasted them back and all the variables match up perfectly.  The database doesn't change though! 
Struggling on this for days....

Comment: You haven't shown your DB structure... are you possibly violating a constraint?

Comment: No signs of this or any conflict that I can see.All columns are set to Not Null as well.

Comment: So the onClick() is invoked because that is where the dialog is dismissed. Did you debug through the code?

Comment: Try changinging you update method to use `updateWithOnConflict` and add the parameter `CONFLICT_FAIL`...  that will cause an error to be thrown if there is some sort of constraint violation instead of silently failing

Comment: I have logged out each variable from beginning to end of method (haven't really logged the boolean that is being returned).  The variables are all as they should be. Is there something out of order with the onClick that you saw?

Comment: No, but the onlybthing I've ever run across that can fail without a peep is a database insert or update.  Make that change and you can definitively rule that out.  My money is on there being an issue there somewhere.

Comment: @Barak I am trying to implement your updateWithOnConflict and looked up the method and parameters on the actual Android website.  Eclipse is not liking this code: 'return database.updateWithOnConflict(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_DEBT, values, whereClause, whereArgs, CONFLICT_FAIL) > 0;'  It has a problem with the CONFLICT_FAIL -- asking if I want to create a constant.  Any suggestions? I like your idea and do want to rule out any conflicts for sure.

Comment: `SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_FAIL`

Comment: I get:  "CONFLICT_FAIL" can not be resolved or is not a field.  I am targeting Android 2.1 on this app.  Did this come afterwards perhaps?  Or am I just doing it in the wrong context?

Comment: @Barak I figured this out, of course it was something simple right in front of us the whole time that was missing.  I have added my answer below.  Check out if you would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the answer.  This is what I WAS doing:

1. Creating a String variable for each column in a specific row of debt.
2. Pre-populating the fields in the dialog with that variable.
3. Then passing the same variables into the update method

For example (simplified):

```
 String name = null;
 EditText et;

 name = debt.getName();
 et.setText(name);

 onclick {
     datasource.updateDebt(name);
 }
```

I was missing a step between 2 and 3.
Setting the variable again, inside the onClick method.  Once the user pressed the update button, the variable had to be RE-SET to the new value of the EditText field.  Like this:

```
 String name = null;
 EditText et;

 name = debt.getName();
 et.setText(name);
 onclick {
     ***name = et.getText().toString();***
     datasource.updateDebt(name);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public boolean updateDebt(long updateId, String debtName, String debtTotal, 
    String debtApr, String paymentGoal) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DEBT_NAME, debtName);
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DEBT_TOTAL, debtTotal);
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_APR, debtApr);
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PAYMENT, paymentGoal);
    return mDb.update(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_DEBT, values, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=" + updateId, null) > 0;
```

And check the boolean that is returned.

Comment: I made the change and the logged the boolean that came out on the other end and it said "true".  Just to double check that the problem is not that I am printing out the results incorrectly, but with the database itself, I went into the database and the number I changed did not go through.

Comment: Update:  Perhaps it would be easier to simply delete the row and insert a new one?  The dialog does contain data from all of the columns and is pre-populated -- so nothing would be left blank.  Though out of principle, I want to know whats going on here.  It obviously is a flaw in the logic, at least I think.